# Form validation script using regex to check for multiple key words across line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

What I need is to check for several key words within a textarea before allowing my students to submit their lesson summaries.
The following regex works fine as long as they don't click enter to create a new paragraph.

```
/^(?=.*\bmodel|models\b)(?=.*\btheory|theories\b)(?=.*\blaw|laws\b)(?=.*\bscale\b)/i;
```

From what I've been reading, it would seem that the following modification to the regex should allow my validation script to read across line breaks, but I haven't had any success.

```
var ck_summary = /^(?=.[\S\s]*\bmodel|models\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\btheory|theories\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\blaw|laws\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\bscale\b)/i;
```

I'm (obviously) a beginner at this and eager to learn. Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong? Many thanks!
Here's my entire summary validation script...

```
var ck_studentid = /^[0-9]{6,6}$/;
var ck_summary = /^(?=.[\S\s]*\bmodel|models\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\btheory|theories\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\blaw|laws\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\bscale\b)/i;

function validate(sumform){
     var studentid = sumform.studentid.value;
     var summary = sumform.summary.value;

     var errors = [];

     if (!ck_studentid.test(studentid)) {
          errors[errors.length] = "Check your Student ID";
     }

     if (!ck_summary.test(summary)) {
          errors[errors.length] = "Make sure you used all of the vocabulary terms AND you spelled them correctly.";
     }

     if (errors.length > 0) {
          reportErrors(errors);
          return false;
     }
     return true;
}

function reportErrors(errors){
     var msg = "Uh oh, looks like we have a problem...\n";
     for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {
          var numError = i + 1;
          msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
     }
     alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I've been reading, it would seem that the following
>   modification to the regex should allow my validation script to read
>   across line breaks, but I haven't had any success.

```
 var ck_summary = /^(?=.[\S\s]*\bmodel|models\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\btheory|theories\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\blaw|laws\b)(?=.[\S\s]*\bscale\b)/i;
```

This didn't work for you because you did not modify it very well.

`.*:` captures every character/word except a newline `\n`,  that was why you were told to modify it to `[\S\s]*` which capture every character/word including a newline `\n`. But looking at your pattern, you didn't totally modify it, you should remove all the dots `.` before `[\S\s]*`.

Your new code should be like this

```
var ck_summary = /^(?=[\S\s]*\bmodel|models\b)(?=[\S\s]*\btheory|theories\b)(?=[\S\s]*\blaw|laws\b)(?=[\S\s]*\bscale\b)/i;
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much James for taking the time to explain my error. I appreciate your time!